# Jersey Rest media streaming not working

Tags: java, spring, rest

I encounter this exception. How can I resolve it?

> m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.digit.spread.controller.VideoController.downloadVideo(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: videoFile (Le fichier sp▒cifi▒ est introuvable)

Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "download.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response downloadVideo(
            @RequestParam(value = "videoId", required = true) String videoId,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String mail = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getName();

        System.out.println(mail+": Download video file starts . . . videoId:"+videoId);
        Video video = videoBean.getVideoObject(videoId);
        InputStream videoFile = videoBean.getVideoFile(video.getFileId());
        long videoFileSize =videoBean.getVideoFileSize(video.getFileId());
        String range = request.getHeader("Range") ;
        final int chunk_size = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunks

        if (range == null) {
            StreamingOutput streamer = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(final OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

                    final FileChannel inputChannel = new FileInputStream("videoFile").getChannel();
                    final WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(output);
                    try {
                        inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
                    } finally {
                        // closing the channels
                        inputChannel.close();
                        outputChannel.close();
                    }
                }
            };
            return Response.ok(streamer).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, videoFileSize).build();
        }

        String[] ranges = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
        final int from = Integer.parseInt(ranges[0]);
        /**
         * Chunk media if the range upper bound is unspecified. Chrome sends "bytes=0-"
         */
        int to = chunk_size + from;
        if (to >= videoFileSize) {
            to = (int) (videoFileSize- 1);
        }
        if (ranges.length == 2) {
            to = Integer.parseInt(ranges[1]);
        }

        final String responseRange = String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", from, to, videoFileSize);
        final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("videoFile", "r");
        raf.seek(from);

        final int len = to - from + 1;
        final MediaStreamer streamer = new MediaStreamer(len, raf);
        Response.ResponseBuilder res = Response.ok(streamer).status(206)
                .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                .header("Content-Range", responseRange)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, streamer.getLenth());

        return Response.ok(streamer).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, videoFileSize).build();
           }
```

Comment: Exception say that is requested video file in not found. try to request another file.

Comment: "FileNotFoundException: videoFile (Le fichier sp▒cifi▒ est introuvable)" Sais it all. The message even translate it into french once more. You can make sure that the file requested exists on the expected path or request another file. In order for it to not break the App you should catch it and return 404 error.

Comment: yes i know  because videoFile is an inputStream and not a file

Comment: hw can i convert it to file

Comment: i want to use inputstream and not a file

Comment: data coming from some other sourceinput stream but i used java.io file i don't know how can i correct this